# Can't edit file in docker-endpoints

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am using crudini to edit a config file in docker-entrypoint.sh

With these commands:

1. exec gosu root crudini
2. gosu root crudini
3. crudini

They all are failed and I get this error

```
error: failed switching to "root": operation not permitted
```

How can I fix it?

This is my Dockerfile and docker-entrypoint.sh
https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/tree/master/10.3

in Dockerfile I install crudini and file docker-entrypoint I add this line:

```
crudini --set /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/mysql.cnf mysqld user $data
```

This is my full docker-entrypoint.sh

https://gist.github.com/quanghnn/fe2df361a7ae351cd03ad723933509a6

Comment: you need to include `Dockerfile` and `docker-entrypoint.sh` to your question

Comment: crudini is not in that `docker-entrypoint.sh`

Comment: The above file is original, I just add crudini later